Lagrange for $f(x,y,z)$ with constraint $g(x,y,z)$
I need to classify extrema of $f=(1+z^2)e^{-y^2}$ on constraint
$$D=\{(x,y,z): x^2+4\leq 8e^{-y^2-z^2}\}.$$
Clearly, a stationary point for $f$ which is also on and within constraint is $(\pm2,0,0)$
Setting up Lagrange:
$$\begin{cases}
0=\lambda(2x)\\
2e^{-y^2}z=\lambda\left(16e^{-y^2-z^2}z\right)\\
-2e^{-y^2}y\left(1+z^2\right)=\lambda\left(16e^{-y^2-z^2}y\right)\\
x^2+4-8e^{\left(-y^2-z^2\right)}= 0
\end{cases}
$$
the only solution I find to the system is $(\pm2,0,0,0)$, which is obviously gives the same value when plugged into $f$.
When I plug the Lagrange system online calculators, $(\pm2,0,0,0)$ is also the only answer I get. According to Weierstrass Theorem I thought there necessarily will be a min and a max of the function. Where am I going wrong?

Min/max could be on the boundary?

Considering the lagrangian
$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda,s) = e^{-y^2} \left(z^2+1\right)+\lambda  \left(s^2+x^2-8 e^{-y^2-z^2}\right)
$$
the stationary conditions are
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcr}
 2 \lambda  x & = & 0\\
 16 \lambda  y e^{-y^2-z^2}-2 e^{-y^2} y \left(z^2+1\right) & = & 0\\
 16 \lambda  z e^{-y^2-z^2}+2 e^{-y^2} z & = & 0\\
 s^2+x^2-8 e^{-y^2-z^2}+4 & = & 0\\
 2 \lambda  s & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
but as $e^{-y^2-z^2}> 0$ and $\lambda$ is generic, this system is equivalent to
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcr}
 \lambda  x & = & 0\\
 \lambda  y -2 e^{-y^2} y \left(z^2+1\right) & = & 0\\
 \lambda  z +2 e^{-y^2} z & = & 0\\
 s^2+x^2-8 e^{-y^2-z^2}+4 & = & 0\\
 \lambda  s & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
with solutions
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
x & y & z & \lambda & s & f\\
 0&0&-\sqrt{\log (2)}&2&0&1+\log (2) \\
 0&0&\sqrt{\log (2)}&-2&0&1+\log (2) \\
 0&-\sqrt{\log (2)}&0&1&0&\frac 12 \\
 0&\sqrt{\log (2)}&0&1&0&\frac 12 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
with $f = e^{-y^2} \left(z^2+1\right)$. As can we see, all the solutions are at the boundary $(s=0)$

The constraint $D$ is a compact solid and therefore, as you have already pointed out, $f$ attains min/max value on it. The gradient of $f$ is null along the segment joining the points $(\pm 2,0,0)$ and the value of $f$ along such segment is $1$. By considering the Hessian of $f$, it can be seen that all those points are saddle points.
As regards the boundary of $D$, we have to solve the system:
$$\begin{cases}
0=λ(2x)\\
-2e^{-y^2}y\left(1+z^2\right)=λ\left(16e^{-y^2-z^2}y\right)\\
2e^{-y^2}z=λ\left(16e^{-y^2-z^2}z\right)\\
x^2+4=8e^{\left(-y^2-z^2\right)}
\end{cases}$$
From the first equation we have TWO cases: $\lambda=0$ or $x=0$.
In the first case we obtain again $(\pm 2,0,0)$. In the second case, it remains to solve
$$\begin{cases}
-2e^{-y^2}y\left(1+z^2\right)=λ\left(16e^{-y^2-z^2}y\right)\\
2e^{-y^2}z=λ\left(16e^{-y^2-z^2}z\right)\\
y^2+z^2=\ln(2)
\end{cases}$$
that is
$$\begin{cases}
2y(e^{-y^2}\left(1+z^2\right)-4\lambda)=0\\
2z(e^{-y^2}-4\lambda)=0\\
y^2+z^2=\ln(2)
\end{cases}
$$
Hence we get $(0,0,\pm\sqrt{\ln(2)})$ with value of $f$ equal to $1+\ln(2)$  and  $(0,\pm\sqrt{\ln(2)},0)$ with value of $f$ equal to $1/2$.
Hence the maximum value of $f$ over $D$ is $1+\ln(2)$ and the minimum value of $f$ over $D$ is $1/2$.
